# How to use result of one query in another query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasicsearch 7.9

**Index**

```
{
  "age": 5
}
{
  "age": 10
}
{
  "age": 11
}
{
  "age": 14
}
{
  "age": 21
}
```

I have to find median of the age from above index.
**What I did:**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "median": {
      "percentiles": {
        "field": "age",
        "percents": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have to take the result and pass the median to search the age greater than median age.

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "age": {
        "gte": 11
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can do like this. But I have to do it in one query.
I am doing it from java rest client. For this simple operation using two queries seems to be not optimal.

Can I do it with single query?
I thought I can do this with scripting. I am not getting how to achieve this.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We need to feed-in output of another aggregation (median/percentile) aggregation into another aggregation to fetch this data. It means we need a `pipeline aggregation`
- Pipeline aggregation are of 2 types : `Parent` & `Sibling`
- **Parent** pipeline aggregation feed on the input from parent aggregation. Since the input from the parent pipeline aggregation which will be the `median` (in this case), and without having context of `documents` they can't be filtered hence it is not possible
- **Sibling** Pipeline aggregation feed on the input from another sibling aggregation. Your use case may be possible if there is any term like `sibling` pipeline aggregation. **But I can't find any**

Hence not possible as of now

Comment: Great. Thank you @Sahil Gupta for clear cut answer.

Comment: Can you please accept/upvote if this answers your question ?